# Which feature make one to use Spring WS over JAX-WS

Tags: java, spring-ws

For SOAP Based Web Services, why one should choose Spring WS over JAX-WS.
I had gone through some article even Spring WS doc feature but still I am not clear.
If I need to convince someone to use Spring WS I can't.

So I want the difference in simple terms that any Web Service Developer can understand.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

I am not going into the details of JAX-WS versus Spring-WS.
You might want to refer to the [link here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web-services/70220-spring-ws-vs-jax-ws)  for details on that and google it.

From my personal experience :

Spring-WS Advantages over JaxWS

1. You want to use a databinding other than JAXB (JibX, Castor or
   others)
2. You want extreme fine grained control on the endpoint mapping strategy
3. You are choosing a WSDL first approach (though many argue that JAXWS also supports a WSDL first approach, it is generally accepted to be more flexible in spring-ws)

JaxWS over SpringWS

1. You want to go for a java first approach
2. You want to make your code flexible (since JAXWS is a specification you can have multiple implementations)
3. You want to use other annotation driven development of JAX-WS